# Convert Event from SeriesMaster to SingleInstance

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am doing an Calendar integration with Office 365 through the Microsoft Graph.

At the moment I have a hard time turning a changing an [Event](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event) from `SeriesMaster` to `SingleInstance`.

When creating an Event, I sent a `recurrence` resulting in it creating a `SeriesMaster` and the respective `Occurrence` Events expected!

When the user requests to change an Event into a single meeting, I update the Event and set the `type` to `SingleInstance` as the API suggests:

Despite returning an `HTTP 200`, office 365 is ignoring my request to change the meeting `type` but does apply the rest of the changes included in the payload (except for recurrence). It acts as if I were just doing an update to the series master.

This is a screenshot of my payload (before converting it to JSON):

[image: Print of my Payload]

I have tried setting `Type` with values of `SingleInstance` and `0` but it does not make a difference.

Anyone have any suggestions or ideas on how to solve?

I want to avoid deleting the Series Master re-creating a Single Instance event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type` property is read-only.

Instead, to convert a `SeriesMaster` into a `SingleInstance` you simply remove the Recurrence Pattern (this will also remove any associated `Occurrence` or `Exception` instances).

You do this by issuing a `PATCH` to `/v1.0/me/events/{event-id}` with a JSON payload of:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{id}
Content-type: application/json

{
    "recurrence": null
}
```

Comment: Its Works! Ty so much!

I would like to ask another question about the microsoft graph API that you can answer:
Is it possible to create meeting rooms through the API? I can list all the meeting rooms but I can not create. I check in the documentation that the API related with meeting rooms is still beta.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, but please file a separate question for this so the community can benefit.